# LogBack cassandra appender for cassandra table or CFS

Tags: logback

I have a java application that will run in Datastax Spark.

I want to store the drive and executor logs in Cassandra table.

Does logback have any appender which will let us copy Spark executor logs to a Cassandra table, or do we have to write a custom appender?

Comment: What are you asking...

Comment: I want to know if just like FileAppender and DbAppender for LogBack, is there an appender which will let us copy Spark executor logs to a Cassandra table. Or do we have to write a custom appender?